# PHP - Generating random numbers within an interval with respect to the mode X

Tags: php, random

I am trying to generate random numbers that their mode is equal to **X** (any real number). As a way of illustration, I expect a function whose header is `rand(int min, int max, int mode)`, and when I call it with the following parameters `rand(min: 1, max: 6, mode: 4)` generates the following:

```
(1,2,4,4,4,5,3) // not exact, but similar
```

I am searching for an optimized way of doing so (although doing it manually would be the worst case, I am out of thoughts).

I have checked [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php), [`rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), and other random generation functions, but have not found what I am looking for.

Any suggests?

Comment: Throw some theory at it: http://learnalgebrafaster.com/mean-median-mode-in-reverse/

Comment: So you want a random number generator that produces less random numbers? Also, when you give an example of the expected result and add _"not exact, but similar"_, then it's pretty hard to know what you actually expect.

Comment: @iainn Thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, well, it is yes, but I believe you would understand more if you read about [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)).

Comment: I know what mode is :-)

Comment: Aw okay, I was just making sure, it is a yes then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 

function generateRandomWithMode($min,$max,$mode,$size){
    if(!($mode >= $min && $mode <= $max)){
        throw new Exception("Mode $mode is not between $min and $max range");       
    }

    $half_count = intval($size / 2);

    /* 
        set mode frequency as half of the size + any random value generated between 0 and half_count. This ensures
        that the mode you provided as the function parameter always remains the mode of the set of random values.
    */
    $mode_frequency = $half_count + rand(0,$half_count);

    $random_values = [];
    $size -= $mode_frequency;

    while($mode_frequency-- > 0) $random_values[] = $mode;
    while($size-- > 0) $random_values[] = rand($min,$max);

    shuffle($random_values);
    return $random_values;
}

print_r(generateRandomWithMode(1,100,4,10));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 63
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 24
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 12
    [9] => 4
)
```